# What libraries to use for Android Project with maps and routing?

Tags: android, google-maps, routes, openstreetmap, android-library

Alongside with my friends I am about to develop an android application. The application will use maps a lot, finding routes, placing markers, drawing predefined routes, stuff like that.

There is this Google Maps APIv2. So I tried it, write some code and looks good. I am able to place markers and draw polylines, however my application will have some predefined routes. One route is set of LatLng points. So I just add these points to PolylineOptions and add it to map. Great, it works.

But these predefined routes will be created in web-based application also using Google Maps APIv2 or similar api/library. Some streets are not straight they are curved so you need to create a lot of LatLng points to get it look nice which is very important. I can do this but I want to put only two LatLng points - at the beginning of the street and at the end.

Here is the image:
[image]

On the left, route has only two LatLng points (red dots) and that is desired shape of line. On the right same route with 2 LatLng points gives me route coloured in light blue, and this is what actually happens if I just add polyline to GoogleMap object. In order to create same effect as in left image, I need to create many LatLng (red dots) points which is not appropriate for those who will create these routes. So this leads us to routing problem which can be solved by using Google Directions API. Which solves the problem of drawing routes with less markers. Basically  what I understood, this API for directions actually creates a lot of these LatLng points that I draw using for-each loop as seen on right part of picture above. And I need to contact Google Web Service for this so I need to have Internet connection - and this is the problem.

Sometimes internet will not be available hence I need some alternative solution. I've heard of Open Street Maps, but I am not sure how to use it and does it needs internet connection for creating these routes.

Is there any free library that offers offline routing and showing maps offline? Basically all map interactions must be done without use of internet.
But it is understandable if internet connection is needed only for the first run of application as it is needed for Google Maps APIv2, well application crashes until I turn on internet, after which any next run I do not need internet..

A web based application will be made for creating these routes and routes will be created by users for whom we develop this application. And as users can be very annoying they will demand some user-friendly and easy interface for creating routes. Telling them that they need to create 100 to 500 points for each route, and if there is 60-70 routes they will gladly say NO to our application.

Any advice? If it is possible, I can write my own routing algorithm for Google Maps to work offline, I am very skilful at "Algorithms and Data Structures" - any guides/tutorials for this? But I guess this map is just set of tiles, and does not have necessary information for finding route.... So please correct If I am mistaken for anything.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Scout SDK](http://developer.skobbler.com/) (provides a free usage quota) as it offers full offline maps, routing & navigation.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look into the open source projects [GraphHopper](https://graphhopper.com/), [Mapsforge](https://github.com/mapsforge/mapsforge) and [OpenScience-VTM](https://github.com/opensciencemap/vtm/) which can do routing and/or maps offline. And all use OpenStreetMap data. Other projects exists of course, have a look [here](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing) and [here](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Android).

Also have a look into the [GraphHopper map matching component](https://github.com/graphhopper/map-matching/) which could be interesting for your specific use case and can work offline too.

(Note I'm the author of GraphHopper)

> If it is possible, I can write my own routing algorithm for Google Maps to work offline

No you can't, the data is not open nor you can buy the data to my knowledge.

Comment: I downloaded DEMO project of GraphHopper from Github, when I built it and run there is local or remote options, but I can't choose anything (for example there is nothing to download)

Answer (score 1):

Another option is [OsmAnd](http://www.osmand.net/). The OSM wiki also has some information about [OsmAnd](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OsmAnd) and even more information about [OSM on Android](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Android) in general as well as pages about [rendering](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Rendering) and [routing](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing).